# Fast Linux Graphics with OPENCV

Tags: opencv, graphics, visualization

I am using openCV to detect lines and curves in some pictures. What I need is a very fast graphing solution.

I have several images taken by several cameras. in a 16*16 grid, with enough overlapping. I am detecting edges, then fitting a curve through it. This much is well doable in < 0.02 seconds.

Problems starts with the graphics. Drawing the intermediate matirces, then upon that several curves and overlaying the raw image on top of all can very well pull up the total time to ~ 1 second. I am on Raspberry pi 4.

I have used Blit with matplotlib to display the results. But I would like to improve speed. My question would be - where can i find some benchmark of different graphic libraries (i am open for c++, d, lua, nim, rust, python, julia and fortran) - where i can read up comparative performance, the definition of the used metric and so on of various graphic libraries in linux.

I am not asking to make recommendations as that is not allowed on StkOvrFl. I merely ask for compiled data which i can use to recommend myself one. Thank you.

Comment: Do you plan to display via X11 or through framebuffer *"directly"* onto hardware?

Comment: for now i am using x11 to add in mouse interactivity and zooming, but i will be open to suggestions with framebuffer too to do the same - if possible at all- can you even use a mouse outside X11?

Comment: Also, are you using all 4 cores - that can make a massive difference on Raspberry Pi...

Comment: on a raspberry pi 4, would it work if i merely rewrite my code to be thread friendly? or do i have to turn "on " some features? And does matplotlib even use multiple core natively? Thank you

Comment: I am having trouble envisaging what you are doing. Do you have 256 cameras if your image grid is 16x16? What size is the final image you are trying to render? What lines/rectangles/ellipses are you overlaying onto it? How many? What sizes? Do you have screenshot?

Comment: I have been experimenting on a Raspberry Pi 4 and can update a full 1024x768 RGB888 image onto the screen in under 1 ms, but I still don't understand what you are trying to do...